# Trying to export to a text file. Can not figure out how to add other info between Jtable info

Tags: java, swing, jtable, export, filewriter

Building a program with Java and am trying to export data to a Text file. I have been working on getting the text doc to come out but I am having problems figuring out how to add text between columns. Right now this code exports the rows in order with a space between each and then each new row gets a ________ to separate it. How can i add things between each column per row. Like an adlib of sort. Like "This is a test and we need {Row1 Column1} and then we need to take {Row1, Column2} and put it in {Row1, Column3}

Im really new to this and I hope one of you can help

---

```
  public void export() throws IOException
    {
  File file = new File("/Users/SamBurton/Desktop/Export.txt");

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
           for(int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++){ 
               for(int j = 0; j < jTable1.getColumnCount(); j++){
                   bw.write(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, j)+" ");
               }
               bw.write("\n_________\n");
           }
           bw.close();
           fw.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Exported");
     }
```

EDIT:

This is just a tiny piece of what i need to fill in. I have labels on my code for specific items that transfer to thing on this text document. (the bolded/caps stuff)

```
<name>**SCENE_SHOT_TAKE**</name>
      <rate>
                                    <timebase>**FRAMERATE**</timebase>
<ntsc>**NTSC-T/F**</ntsc> 
     </rate>
                                            <alphatype>none</alphatype> 
<pixelaspectratio>**PIXELASPECTRATIO-T/F**</pixelaspectratio> 
                             <anamorphic>**ANAMORPHIC-T/F**</anamorphic> 
<file id="file-**X+1**">
```

Im trying to talk this out the best i can. I need certain cells in my jtable to line up with the CAPS parts of this output document. So each cell corresponds to a fill in. Then at after each row this same thing above goes again with the info from the next row down in the table

Comment: WHAT are you trying to achieve? Can you post a text file output of the desired result, and format it as if it were code?

Comment: I'm thinking that you might want to use `String.format(....)` or a `java.util.Formatter`, or something similar, but I'm not really sure of your ultimate goal, so again any clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: At a guess, you need an array with the text you want pre-fix each column with

Comment: Also Hovercraft Full Of Eels. I am really new to code in general so i am sorry. It is hard for me to type out what i want exactly. Not super complected just cant put it into words well

Comment: Whoa, don't post important information in comments. Please [edit] your original question and then comment to us when you've done this.

Comment: Edited. Sorry.....